# hTop: Homotopy is compatible with sums

Tags: algebraic-topology, category-theory, homotopy-theory

In Tom Dieck's Algebraic Topology pg29, he wrote, (hTop is category with topological spaces as objects, homotopy equivalence classes as morphisms. Here  $[X,Y]$ denotes $Hom_{hTop}(X,Y)$. )

> Homotopy is compatible with sums and products. Let $i_k :X_k \rightarrow \coprod X_j$ be injection. Then
>   $$[\coprod X_j, Y] \rightarrow \prod [X_j,Y], [f] \mapsto [f \circ i_k ]$$
>   is a well defined **bijection**. In otherwords, sum in Top represent sum in **hTop**.

Why is it a bijection?

---

I get that it is a surjection.

*Surjectivity:* Let $Y$ be an object in **hTop**, $([f_j)] \in \prod [X_j,Y]$ (setwise product). Picking representative $f'_j \in [f_j]$, exists $f: \coprod X_j \rightarrow Y$, such that $f \circ i_k = f'_k$, hence same for its homotopy class.

*Injectivity (Incomplete):* Suppose exists $g: \coprod X_j \rightarrow Y$, such that $g \circ i_j = f''_j \in [f_j]$. Such that $G_j: X_j \times [0,1] \rightarrow Y$, with $G_j: f'_j \simeq f''_j$. Exists map, $ \coprod G_j: \coprod (X_j \times [0,1]) \rightarrow Y $. 
But we need a map $\Big( \coprod X_j \Big) \times [0,1] \rightarrow Y$ for $g \simeq f$ which I don't see how to complete.

Comment: Note that $(\bigsqcup X_j)\times [0,1]=\bigsqcup(X_j\times[0,1])$. Clearly they have the same underlying sets, and the topologies coincide through the definitions of the disjoint and product topologies.

Comment: Using your notation on the LHS you have elements $(x_j,t)$ where $x_j \in X_j$ (the $t$ has no index), this corresponds to an element $(x_j,t) \in X_j \times [0,1]$ on the RHS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the comment by Tyrone suggested you have a bijection between the homotopies of maps $(\coprod X_i) \rightarrow Y$ and collections of homotopies of maps $X_i \rightarrow Y$.

So to complete your proof of injectivity you have just to glue together the homotopies $G_j$ to get one between the maps $g$ and $f$.

I will made explicit the bijection I claimed: take an homotopy 
$H \colon (\coprod_i X_i) \times [0,1] \rightarrow Y$, by the homeomorphism $(\coprod_i X_i)\times [0,1] \cong \coprod_i X_i \times [0,1]$ we obtain a map $H' \colon \coprod_i X_i \times [0,1] \rightarrow Y$. Now by the universal property of the coproduct we have that this corresponds uniquely to a collection of maps $G_i \colon X_i \times [0,1] \rightarrow Y$.

Notice that in this construction I used precomposition with an isomorphism and the universal property of the coproduct to get a map of sets
$Hom((\coprod_i X_i)\times [0,1],Y ) \cong Hom(\coprod_i X_i \times [0,1],Y ) \cong \prod_i Hom(X_i \times [0,1], Y)$ 
which is composition of two bijections, thus a bijection.

But you can also write explicitly the inverse.

Comment: Thanks N.B. I am actually struggling with the homeomorphism of two sets. Is this argument correct: 

 Let $U$ be an open basis in LHS. Then $U= A \times B$, where $A \cap X_j$ is open for all $j$, and $B \subseteq [0,1]$ is open. In RHS, $$U \cap (X_j \cap [0,1]) = (A \cap X_j) \times B$$ which is open.  

Conversely, Let $U$ be an open basis in RHS. Then $$U = \bigcup_j (V_j \times B_j)$$ for some open sets $V_j $ in $X_j$, $B_j \subseteq [0,1]$. In LHS, this is a union of open sets, hence open.

Comment: Yes, the argument is correct.